# How significant is the benefit of checking IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered?

Tags: asp.net, .net

How significant is the benefit of checking `IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered` before `RegisterClientScriptInclude`?

From an [example in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx145dw2.aspx):

```
' Check to see if the include script is already registered.
If (Not cs.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(cstype, csname)) Then    
    cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(cstype, csname, ResolveClientUrl(csurl))
End If
```

Which states:

> Note that if the logic to check for the existing client script include
>   were removed, there would still not be duplicate client scripts in the
>   rendered page because the RegisterClientScriptInclude method checks
>   for duplicates. **The benefit of checking is to reduce unnecessary
>   computation.**

I'm wondering about the highlighted sentence. What unnecessary computation?

To me it seems the other way around. Using `IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered` before `RegisterClientScriptInclude` should/would check for the registered script two times (thus added unnecessary computation instead of reduced).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered` is simple check in Dictionary if the script all ready register, is a very fast check, with out many code.

```
public bool IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(Type type, string key)
{
    if (type == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
    }
    return ((this._registeredClientScriptBlocks != null) && 
     this._registeredClientScriptBlocks.Contains(
        CreateScriptIncludeKey(type, key, false)));
}
```

The `RegisterClientScriptInclude` from the other hand, contains a little more code until is reach the check of the existing.

```
internal void RegisterClientScriptInclude(Control control, Type type, string key, string url)
{
    IScriptManager scriptManager = this._owner.ScriptManager;
    if ((scriptManager != null) && scriptManager.SupportsPartialRendering)
    {
        scriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(control, type, key, url);
    }
    else
    {
        this.RegisterClientScriptInclude(type, key, url);
    }
}

internal void RegisterClientScriptInclude(Type type, string key, string url, bool isResource)
{
    if (type == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        throw ExceptionUtil.ParameterNullOrEmpty("url");
    }
    string script = "\r\n<script src=\"" + HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(url) + "\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";
    this.RegisterScriptBlock(CreateScriptIncludeKey(type, key, isResource), script, ClientAPIRegisterType.ClientScriptBlocks);
}

internal void RegisterScriptBlock(ScriptKey key, string script, ClientAPIRegisterType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case ClientAPIRegisterType.ClientScriptBlocks:
            this.RegisterScriptBlock(key, script, ref this._registeredClientScriptBlocks, ref this._clientScriptBlocks, false);
            break;

        case ClientAPIRegisterType.ClientScriptBlocksWithoutTags:
            this.RegisterScriptBlock(key, script, ref this._registeredClientScriptBlocks, ref this._clientScriptBlocks, true);
            break;

        case ClientAPIRegisterType.ClientStartupScripts:
            this.RegisterScriptBlock(key, script, ref this._registeredClientStartupScripts, ref this._clientStartupScripts, false);
            break;

        case ClientAPIRegisterType.ClientStartupScriptsWithoutTags:
            this.RegisterScriptBlock(key, script, ref this._registeredClientStartupScripts, ref this._clientStartupScripts, true);
            break;
    }
    if (this._owner.PartialCachingControlStack != null)
    {
        foreach (BasePartialCachingControl control in this._owner.PartialCachingControlStack)
        {
            control.RegisterScriptBlock(type, key, script);
        }
    }
}


private void RegisterScriptBlock(ScriptKey key, string script, ref ListDictionary scriptBlocks, ref ArrayList scriptList, bool needsScriptTags)
{
    if (scriptBlocks == null)
    {
        scriptBlocks = new ListDictionary();
        scriptList = new ArrayList();
    }
    if (!scriptBlocks.Contains(key))
    {
        Tuple<ScriptKey, string, bool> tuple = new Tuple<ScriptKey, string, bool>(key, script, needsScriptTags);
        scriptBlocks.Add(key, null);
        scriptList.Add(tuple);
    }
}
```

Comment: So the same check happens some checks and couple of calls later. Seems like no big deal here. Thanks.

Comment: @Qtax If you call it many times, then is something - at least on a complicate application that you need to make it run as fast as possible :).